# How to toggle graphics in a ClickPane

Tags: graphics, dynamic, user-interface

I am trying to make a simple hundred chart with squares that will toggle on and off when clicked.  I have a start, I can click to fill a square, but have no idea how to click on a filled square and "un-fill" it.   I would appreciate any help or advice on how to proceed.

```
list = {};

ClickPane[
 Dynamic[
  Graphics[{
    GrayLevel[0.8], Line /@ Table[{{i, 0}, {i, 10}}, {i, 0, 10}],
    Line /@ Table[{{0, i}, {10, i}}, {i, 0, 10}],
    Rectangle[#, # + {1, 1}] & /@ list}]], AppendTo[list, Floor[#]] &]
```

Comment...

I just saw FlipView and here is a very crude way to answer my question, not elegant, but it works.  Would still value input...

```
lines = { GrayLevel[0.8], Line /@ Table[{{i, 0}, {i, 10}}, {i, 0, 10}],
  Line /@ Table[{{0, i}, {10, i}}, {i, 0, 10}]}

rectangles = Flatten[Table[
    FlipView[{{White, Rectangle[{i, j}, {i, j} + {1, 1}]},
      {GrayLevel[0.9], Rectangle[{i, j}, {i, j} + {1, 1}]}}], {i, 0, 
     9, 1}, {j, 0, 9, 1}]];

Graphics[{
  rectangles,
  lines}]
```

Comment: The lines are not necessary if you include `EdgeForm`, i.e., `Graphics[{EdgeForm[GrayLevel[0.8]], rectangles}]`

Answer (score 5):

Is the `ClickPane` an inescapable requirement? Would something like the following help at all?

```
rec = 
  FlipView[{
    Graphics@ {FaceForm[LightGray],   Rectangle[]},
    Graphics@ {FaceForm[Darker@Gray], Rectangle[]}
  }];

Grid[
  ConstantArray[rec, {3, 3}],
  Frame -> All, Spacings -> {0, 0}
]
```

[image: a grid with some clicked rectangles]

Answer (score 3):

Create a single `Rectangle` and `Translate` it:

```
rectangle = FlipView @ 
    Thread[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm /@ {LightGray, Darker @ Gray}, Rectangle[]}];

n = 4;

coords = Tuples[Range @ n, 2];

Graphics[Translate[rectangle, #] & /@ coords]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is no out of the box function. However, you can achieve this with a dynamic button:

```
n = 5;
Grid[Table[
  DynamicModule[{x = White}, 
   Button[StringForm["``,``", i, j], x = If[x === White, Red, White], 
    Background -> Dynamic[x]]], {i, n}, {j, n}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[labeledRectangles]
labeledRectangles[o : OptionsPattern[]][n_, faceStyles_: {LightGray, Darker @ Gray}, 
    edgeStyle_: Black] := Module[{range = Range @ n}, 
  Graphics[Translate[FlipView @ Thread[
   {EdgeForm[edgeStyle], FaceForm /@ faceStyles,  Rectangle[], 
   {Text[Style[Row[{n + 1 - Last@#, First@#}, "×"], 
      Last@faceStyles, FontSize -> Scaled[.02], Opacity[1]], {.5, .5}, Center], 
    Text[Style[Times[First@#, n + 1 - Last@#], 
      First@faceStyles, FontSize -> Scaled[.04], Opacity[1]], {.5, .5}, Center]}}],
    #] & /@ Tuples[range, 2], 
   o, Frame -> True, 
   FrameTicks -> {{#, #} &[{# + .5, n + 1 - #} & /@ range], 
      {#, #} &[{# + .5, #} & /@ range]}]]
```

***Examples:***

```
labeledRectangles[ImageSize -> Large][10]
```

[image]

```
labeledRectangles[ImageSize -> Large][10, {Black, White}, Directive[Gray, Thick]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, looks amazing.  When I copy and paste and evaluate I am getting an error...  Range::range: Range specification in Range[n] does not have appropriate bounds.   Not sure what I might be doing wrong there...?

Comment: @TomDeVries, I copy/pasted the wrong code block. Fixed now.

Comment: Fantastic,  definitely a great application of a hundred chart, lots for me to learn here!

Answer (score 2):

Using a labeled `MatrixPlot` with [`EventHandler`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EventHandler.html) to modify labels on left-mouse click and to [`Speak`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Speak.html) the cell contents on right-mouse click:

```
ClearAll[labeledMat, multiplicationTable]

infoButton = Inset[Tooltip[Graphics[{Blue, Disk[], 
    Text[Style["i", 14, Italic, Bold, White, FontFamily -> "Times"], {0, 0}]}, 
   PlotRange -> 1.2, ImageSize -> 24],
 "left click to" <> ToString[Style[" see ", Italic], StandardForm] <> 
 "the result\nright click to" <> ToString[Style[" hear ", Italic], StandardForm]], 
   Scaled@{0, 1}, {-1., -2}];

labeledMat[mat_] := MapIndexed[
  Text[Style[# /. {1 -> ((Length @ mat + 1 - #2[[2]]) #2[[1]]), 
       0 -> Row[{Length @ mat + 1 - #2[[2]], #2[[1]]}, "×"]}, # /.
    {0 -> FontSize -> Scaled[.025], 1 -> FontSize -> Scaled[.05]}], #2 - .5] &, mat, {2}]

multiplicationTable[n_: 10, o : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 DynamicModule[{m = ConstantArray[0, {n, n}]}, Dynamic @ Panel @
  EventHandler[
     MatrixPlot[Reverse @ Transpose @ m, o, 
      ColorRules -> {0 -> LightGray, 1 -> Gray}, 
      Mesh -> All, 
      ImageSize -> 1 -> 50,
      ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, 36}}, 
      Epilog -> {infoButton, labeledMat[m]}], 
   {{"MouseClicked", 1} :>
     With[{p = Clip[Ceiling @ MousePosition["Graphics"], {1, n}, {None, None}]},
        If[FreeQ[None]@p, m[[## & @@ p]] = 1 - m[[## & @@ p]]]], 
    {"MouseClicked", 2} :>
     With[{p = Clip[Ceiling @ MousePosition["Graphics"], {1, n}, {None, None}]},
        If[FreeQ[None]@p, 
          With[{a = p[[1]], b = n + 1 - p[[2]]},             
           If[m[[## & @@ p]] > 0, Speak[StringJoin[ToString[b] <> " times ", 
             ToString @ a, " equals ", ToString[a b]]]
           Speak[HoldForm[b a]]]]]]}]]
```

***Examples:***

```
multiplicationTable[10, ColorRules -> {0 -> Yellow, 1 -> Red}]
```

[image]

Comment: Another great example with lots of good examples of programming methods and applications!